# How can I see my views of laravel with my centos server

Tags: php, laravel-5, centos6

I have my laravel project in the folder `/var/www/html/myproject` and when I type the route in my browser example: `127.0.0.2/api/v1/cuentas` (because I use a public IP) I can't see my view, it throughts me

```
Not Found
The requested URL /api/v1/cuentas was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at (ip) Port 80
```

- The `cuentas` file is php
- I set the permissions

My route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function()
{
    Route::resource('cuentas','cuentaPruebaController');
});
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\cuentum;

class cuentaPruebaController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        try {

            $response = [
                'cuentas' => []
            ];
            $statusCode = 200;
            $cuenta = \App\cuentum::all();

            foreach ($cuenta as $item) {

                $response['cuentas'][] = [
                    'id_cuenta' => $item->id_cuenta,
                    'nombre' => $item->nombre,
                    'apellido' => $item->apellido,
                    'ci' => $item->ci,
                    'domicilio' => $item->domicilio,
                    'telefono' => $item->telefono,
                    'dispositivo_id' => $item->dispositivo_id,
                    'estado' => $item->estado,
                ];
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $statusCode = 404;
        } finally {
            return \Response::json(array($response, $statusCode));
        }
    }
 }
```

And return a json file.

The route is available:

[image]

What's wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: What is `accounts` file? Controller?

Comment: yes...is a controller

Comment: please share your controller and routes.php

Comment: The question is updated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use `php artisan route:list`, this will give you list of routes available. Check those and share here as well

Comment: question updated again! (with picture)

Comment: I got this error in log `[Wed May 11 21:27:16 2016] [error] [client ip] File does not exist: /var/www/html/nueveonce/api
` How I can I point the route then? I'm lost